# React Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm having trouble when trying to run a React program. I am just trying to use NPM run build, and the program is crashing with this exact line

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'create-react-class' in '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Desktop/Gitlab_builds/6e121ce4/0/web/ChatApp/src/views/Pages/Tasks'

I have already run NPM install create-react-class, so I am not sure why it is unable to find the module. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you installed the module globally by appending `-g` to npm install command line OR in the root directory of your project by simply running npm install command while your current working directory was root directory of project.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it did not work. I am still getting the same error. Not sure why it says module not found, when I have tried to install it a few different ways

Comment: Use `npm i create-react-class --save` to save it in package.json.

Comment: When I ran that line of code, I got these exact errors

+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.5.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-transition-group@^1.1.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0

Any idea of how to resolve them?

Comment: What version of react are you running?

Comment: I believe it is "version": "1.0.0-alpha.6"